# Safari can't load data returned by server properly

Tags: php, vue.js, safari, mobile-safari

I recently develped and deployed website carspeedyrental.com Some of the clients reported that website doesn't show available cars at all. This only happens when they are using iphone safari browser. I have tested it  on most browsers on android, windows and used browserstack to tested it on ios safari browser which all worked perfectly fine. It only happens  when customer uses iphone safari browser. I don't have iPhone and can't test or view logs. My front end is written in vueJs, and back end is in php. I have never had such problem before so don't know how to approach that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there any console or network logs errors messages?

Comment: no error messages on chrome and opera browser, it does give me some warnings on firefox. you are more than welcome to go to the website and check, it will show you everything realtime. carspeedyrental.com

Answer (score 1):

Please ask you clients to share on what iPhone devices they have tested and maybe you can try on those devices on Browserstack.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tested it on my friends (iphone se, Iphone12). Again it doesn't work on iPhone safari browser but works on everything else.  also I don't think Browserstack doesn't give me logs for safari browser inside phone emulator.

Comment: Thank you for your response, let me make it clear that if your test does not work on a real iOS device then surely it will not work on any of the remote infrastructure providers like BrowserStack. Because they also use real devices only (not emulators) at their data centres. Apart from this, BrowserStack do provide you appium, device logs, etc. for the test you run, you can check their documenttation for more help.